# "Resource out of synch with the filesystem" - but can I still get it somehow?

Tags: eclipse, editor, revision-history, undelete

I've mistakenly overwritten a file I was working on in Eclipse. Now I'm getting a message saying

> Resource out of synch with the filesystem

and suggesting I refresh with F5. Can I, instead of refreshing, get that "resource"? It would mean restoring my accidentally-overwritten file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click on the file and try 'Replace With > Local History'. Eclipse will show you what versions of the file it has in the local history, but local history is only kept for a few days.

Comment: Well, I'll accept even though I often get "no local history" - I'm assuming there's nothing else I can do.